# How to remove specific component from a list generated by a .map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, vite

I have a `EventCell.tsx` component, when user clicks on it, event is created by adding element to `components` state. Then .map() list of `Event.tsx` components is rendered. If you click on event itself, modal will pop out, and you will be able to rename or delete event. Renaming is working fine. But when click on delete, it's always deleting last component, no matter on what event I clicked to delete. Basically even if I click on first event and click `Delete` the last event will be deleted.
I debugged and discovered that deletion is working fine: when I click on the first event in list to delete it, first element of `components` array is deleted. But on render still last event is deleted.
I think it's because after `onDelete` function, `components` array length is decreased by 1, so .map()
just renders one component less, which means last component is deleted.

(I deleted ClassNames for better readability, UI is working fine)
Code:

`EventCell.tsx`

```js
const EventCell: React.FC<Props> = ({
    onClick,
    children,
    className,
    isActive = false,
}) => {
    const [components, setComponents] = useState([] as number[])
    const [renamingEventNow, setRenamingEventNow] = useStore((state) => [
        state.renamingEventNow,
        state.setRenamingEventNow,
    ]) // is some event renaming right now globally?

    const createEvent = () => {
        if (renamingEventNow === true) return setRenamingEventNow(false)
        setRenamingEventNow(true)
        setComponents([...components, components.length])
    }
    const deleteEvent = (index: number) => {
        const eventsArrayCopy = [...components]
        eventsArrayCopy.splice(index, 1)
        setComponents(eventsArrayCopy)
        setRenamingEventNow(false)
    }

    return (
        
            <div
                onClick={() => createEvent()}
                className="w-full h-[5.5rem] absolute"
            ></div>
            <div>
                {components.map((events, index) => (
                    <Event
                        key={index}
                        index={index}
                        onDelete={() => deleteEvent(index)}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`Event.tsx`

```js
const Event: React.FC<Props> = ({
    className,
    onClick = () => null,
    onDelete,
    index,
    children,
}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        setRenamingEventNow(true)
    }, [])

    const [renamingEventNow, setRenamingEventNow] = useStore((state) => [
        state.renamingEventNow,
        state.setRenamingEventNow,
    ]) // is some event renaming right now globally?

    const [isRenaming, setIsRenaming] = useState(true) //is this event renaming now?
    const [name, setName] = useState('')

    const finishRenaming = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (name === '') setName('New Event')
        setIsRenaming(false)
        setRenamingEventNow(false)
    }

    const onRename = () => {
        setRenamingEventNow(true)
        setIsRenaming(true)
    }
    return (
        <div
            onClick={onRename}
        >
            {name}
            {index} // added this for easier debugging
            {isRenaming && (
                <form
                    onSubmit={finishRenaming}
                >
                    <input
                        autoFocus
                        type="text"
                        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                        value={name}
                    ></input>
                    <div>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                        >
                            Done
                        </button>
                        <button
                            onClick={onDelete}
                            type="reset"
                        >
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            )}

            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

As I said I tried debugging, and discovered that deletion in `onDelete` function is working fine. The problem is that .map() still removes last `Event` component, so on render last event is removed no matter on what event I clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use index as key and then remove an item from array, React uses the key to determine which items changed. If you remove an item from the middle of array, indices of items after it will decrease by one causing React to think last item was removed.

Instead of storing numbers in your components, store objects with unique ID's. When adding a new event generate a unique ID for it. You can use a package like uuid for that.

`EventCell.tsx:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'; // Import the uuid library

const EventCell: React.FC<Props> = ({ ... }) =>{
    const [components, setComponents] = useState([] as { id: string }[])

    const createEvent = () =>{
        if (renamingEventNow === true) return setRenamingEventNow(false)
        setRenamingEventNow(true)
        setComponents([...components, {id:uuidv4()}]) // uuid to generate a unique ID
    }

    const deleteEvent=(id: string)=>{
        setComponents(components.filter(event=>event.id !== id))
        setRenamingEventNow(false)
    }

    return(
        ...
            {components.map(event=>(
                <Event
                    key={event.id}
                    onDelete={() => deleteEvent(event.id)}
                    ...
                />
            ))}
        ...
    )
}
```

`Event.tsx:`

```
const Event: React.FC=({ onDelete, ... })=>{
    ...
    return(
        ...
        <button
            onClick={onDelete}
            type="reset"
        >
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Glad that you sacrificed your time for the answer. It was easy to understand and actually working. Again, thank you)